# Grid Search Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nan, grid-search

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

This is the error that appears when I run my code for Grid Search using scikit library.

```
df= pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(df.drop(columns=['SalePrice']), df['SalePrice'], random_state=1)
mlp = MLPRegressor(max_iter=1000, hidden_layer_sizes=(667, 45, 45), random_state=1 )
parameter_space = {
    'activation': ['tanh', 'relu', 'identity', 'logistic'],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'alpha': [0.0001, 0.05],
    'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive'],
}

clf = GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, n_jobs=-1, cv=3, scoring='neg_mean_squared_log_error')
clf.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
```

I tried use dropna() and make sure I don't have any nan value

```
df.isnull().any().any()
# False
```

But still returns the same error. Why?

Comment: Check df size [df.shape], it might be empty, or the dataframe has non numeric values

Comment: df size = `(840, 312)`